# Android Studio webview - Disable context menu on double click

Tags: android, webview, onclicklistener, disable

I would like to disable any user interaction on my webview.
With this code it is possible to deactivate the menu (copy text) on long clickable:

```
   webview.setLongClickable(false);
    webview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But on double click I still get this menu:
[image]

Maybe there is an option to disable also this popup menu?